# Comparing Char with == and single quote gives warning

Tags: c, char, comparison, single-quotes

I am writing a program to calculate cosines and I should read the user input for angles given in degree (°) or radians (r). If the angle were to be given in degrees, it should be converted into radians (hence I used the if-else statement). However, when I compare char with `==` and single quote I get the following warning:

```
warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
if((unit != '°') && (unit != 'r'))
```

This is my full code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

// Prototype
void calc_cos(double, char);

int main (void)
{
    double angle;
    char unit;
    printf("PLease give an angle and its unit in degrees (°) or radians (r) for cosinus calculation\n");
    if((unit != '°') && (unit != 'r'))
    {
        printf("ERROR. Unit is not in '°' or 'r'. Aborting...\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
    scanf("%lf %c", &angle, &unit);
    calc_cos(angle, unit);
    }
    return 0;
}

void calc_cos(double angle, char unit)
{
    double results=0;
    if(unit == '°')
    {
        angle = angle*M_PI/180;
    }
    else if(unit == 'r')
    {
        angle = angle;
    }
    results = cos(angle);
    printf("cos(%lf rad) = %lf\n", angle, results);
}
```

Comment: As the warning (multi-character character) tells you, `'°'` is not of type `char`.

Comment: C data types were invented before UTF-8 and Unicode.  Think of `char` as just a synonym for "byte."  For characters that are not represented in one byte (like º when you are in UTF-8 mode), you cannot store them in a `char`. You can use a wide character type, and implementation-defined type, or devise your own way of handling Unicode (e.g., using a `uint32_t` to store Unicode code points as UCS-4).

Comment: @goodvibration: In C, no character constant is of type `char`. They are all `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have indicated in the comments, the degree (`°`) character is not encoded as a single byte in the ASCII system; rather, it is interpreted by the compiler as a sequence of (probably) two bytes.

There are various ways around this. One would be to use the `wchar_t` type for your `unit` variable, and the corresponding wide literals for the comparisons (`L'°'` and `L'r'`, in place of `'°'` and `'r'`); however, this would require changing (at least) your `scanf` call to use the `%lc` format specifier, but you would almost certainly be better of, in that case, using the `wprintf` and `wscanf` "wide-character" versions of the standard I/O functions.

However, even with such changes, you are likely to encounter problems reading the `°` character in a console application, as there are numerous different encoding systems that can be used. So, in my opinion, you would be better off using a simple letter `d` to specify units of degrees.

Also, even with any of these fixes, there are some other issues in your code. The most notable is that you are testing the `unit` variable **before** it has been given. Code with this corrected, plus a few other suggested improvements (and using the `d` for degrees) is shown below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES /// Many compilers require this to give the "M_PI" definition
#include <math.h>

// Prototype
void calc_cos(double, char);

int main(void)
{
    double angle;
    char unit;
    printf("Please give an angle and its unit in degrees (d) or radians (r) for cosinus calculation\n");
    scanf("%lf %c", &angle, &unit); /// MUST read "unit" BEFORE testing it!
    if ((unit != 'd') && (unit != 'r')) {
        printf("ERROR. Unit is not in 'd' or 'r'. Aborting...\n");
        return 0;
    }
    calc_cos(angle, unit);
    return 0;
}

void calc_cos(double angle, char unit)
{
    double results = 0;
    if (unit == 'd') {
        angle = angle * M_PI / 180;
    }
//  else if (unit == 'r') { /// This block is unnecessary
//      angle = angle;
//  }
    results = cos(angle);
    printf("cos(%lf rad) = %lf\n", angle, results);
}
```

Please feel free to ask for any further clarification and/or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In C a char is one byte but the degrees sign typically needs more than one byte, at least in the UTF-8 character encoding. One solution is to store the unit in a character array instead, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char unit[4 + 1];
    int count;

    count = scanf("%4s", unit);
    if (count == 1) {
        if (strcmp(unit, "°") == 0) {
            puts("degrees chosen");
        } else if (strcmp(unit, "r") == 0) {
            puts("radians chosen");
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid unit: %s\n", unit);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A UTF-8 character is one to four bytes long and the format specifier `%4s` makes sure that at most four bytes are read.

However, a simpler approach is to instead use the letter "d" for degrees.